# What do you call input class="gLFyf" vs input.gLFyF (vocabulary help needed)

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

In Chrome DevTools, the element tab shows the constructed DOM and I can click on elements in the DOM which also highlights the element on the page. [Image of both versions shown in DevTools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DB5S1.png)

If the DOM shows:

```
<input class="gLFyf">
```

Then the page highlight will show:

```
input.gLFyF
```

I realise these are two ways of writing the same thing, I also realise the former is HTML style and the latter follows CSS conventions. However, I lack the vocabulary to properly refer to either.

What do I call each format?

Eg. would it make sense to refer to `<input class="gLFyf">` as HTML syntax and `input.gLFyF` as CSS syntax? Is there a more widely accepted way to differentiate and name them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gLFyf` is the name of the class which is an attribute that can be referred to in the stylesheet to match styles with elements of that class on the page.

A class leads with a period (.) - whereas an ID would lead with a hash (#).

So `.gLFyf` is a class.

And `#gLFyf` would be an ID.

It is a class, whether viewing HTML markup or the DOM inspector. They both refer to the same thing as you already state.

[This may be of some use/reference](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_classes.asp).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the resource Sorry, just to clarify, I understand that in both instances in my example `gLFyf` is the class, my question is what to call the specific formats that show the element structure. Eg. would it make sense to refer to `<input class="gLFyf">` as HTML syntax and `input.gLFyF` as CSS syntax?

Comment: @Vicky one is HTML markup and the other is a DOM inspector. There isn't any more to it than that... :D

Comment: Yup, never mind I see where I was getting confused. Thanks for the help, I've selected it as best answer :)